# Typing for function-constructors

Tags: typescript

I have the class:

```
class Parent {
    method(): string {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

And I need a child of this class. In TypeScript it is simple *class Child extends Parent*. But for some reasons I need to use the "old" method:

```
function Fake(): void {}
Fake.prototype = Parent.prototype;
function Child(): void {
}
Child.prototype = new Fake();
```

Can I somehow make it clear to the compiler that Child extends Parent?

Unsuccessful attempt:

```
const Child: typeof Parent = <typeof Parent>function Child(): void {
    // ...
};
```

**Explanation of my strange desire**

1. I need a function that (depending on the parameters) creates classes that extendeds different parent classes.

For example, I want create exception class that inherited from Error or from TypeError.

2. This function will be used in pure JavaScript (not in TypeScript) and  there just do not use extends.

Comment: also.. why do you want a function to extend a class?

Comment: toskv, as I know, classes are functions. Therefore, there is nothing wrong with that Child is function (as Parent too). Unfortunately, I need this method in this place instead the keyword extends.

Comment: maybe it would be better to try to find a workaround to the reason that forces you to use this "old" method...

Comment: indeed they are compiled to function in the end, but class extension is the way to go. what error are you getting when trying to do class extension?

Comment: toskv, DaniCE, I updated my question

Comment: so, you want a factory function that creates dynamic OO hierarchies based on the information it receives?

Comment: Yes something like that. Function that returns class (function-constructor). And problem not in implementation of this function but explain results of this function to TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe class extension is not the preferred way to go in this case.

TypeScript does offer support for mixins.

They allow you to create classes by combining parts of other classes.

It would look something like this:

```js
class ErrorKindA {
    errorMessage: string;
    getError(): string {
        return this.errorMessage;
    }
}

class ErrorKindB  {
    information: string;
    getInformation(): string {
        return this.information;
    }

}

class Child implements ErrorKindA, ErrorKindB {
    constructor() {

        var fromA = this.getError();
        var fromB = this.getInformation();
    }
    otherThing: string= "abc";
    getThing(): string {
        return this.otherThing;
    }
    // A
    errorMessage: string ="errror ";
    getError:()=> string;

    // B
    information: string = "info stuff";
    getInformation: () => string;
}




applyMixins(Child, [ErrorKindA, ErrorKindB]);




enum Kind {
    A, B
}

function createChild(kind: Kind){
    if(kind == Kind.A) {
        applyMixins(Child, [ErrorKindA]);
        return Child;
    } else {
        applyMixins(Child, [ErrorKindB]);
        return Child;
    }

} 

////////////////////////////////////////
// In your runtime library somewhere
////////////////////////////////////////

function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        })
    });
}
```

You can see a working example of this [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20ErrorKindA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20errorMessage%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20getError()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.errorMessage%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ErrorKindB%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20information%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20getInformation()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.information%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Child%20implements%20ErrorKindA%2C%20ErrorKindB%20%7B%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0A%0A%09%09var%20fromA%20%3D%20this.getError()%3B%0A%09%09var%20fromB%20%3D%20this.getInformation()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20otherThing%3A%20string%3D%20%22abc%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20getThing()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.otherThing%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%2F%2F%20A%0A%09errorMessage%3A%20string%20%3D%22errror%20%22%3B%0A%09getError%3A()%3D%3E%20string%3B%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20B%0A%09information%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22info%20stuff%22%3B%0A%09getInformation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A%0AapplyMixins(Child%2C%20%5BErrorKindA%2C%20ErrorKindB%5D)%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A%0Aenum%20Kind%20%7B%0A%09A%2C%20B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20createChild(kind%3A%20Kind)%7B%0A%09if(kind%20%3D%3D%20Kind.A)%20%7B%0A%09%09applyMixins(Child%2C%20%5BErrorKindA%5D)%3B%0A%09%09return%20Child%3B%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09applyMixins(Child%2C%20%5BErrorKindB%5D)%3B%0A%09%09return%20Child%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%20%0A%7D%20%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20In%20your%20runtime%20library%20somewhere%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0A%0Afunction%20applyMixins(derivedCtor%3A%20any%2C%20baseCtors%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20derivedCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20baseCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%09applyMixins(Child%2C%20%5BErrorKindA%2C%20ErrorKindB%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0A%09console.log(x.getInformation())%3B%0A%09console.log(x.getError())%3B%0A%09button.textContent%20%3D%20x.getThing()%3B%0A%09x.information%20%3D%20%22removed%22%3B%0A%09%0A%09applyMixins(Child%2C%20%5BErrorKindA%5D)%3B%0A%09var%20y%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0A%09console.log(y.getInformation())%3B%0A%09console.log(y.getError())%3B%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A).

And you can find out more about mixins in TypeScript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#mixins).

Answer (score 1):

You must have omitted some detail because the following code works:

```
class Parent {
    method(): string {
        console.log("test");
        return "result";
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {    
}

let c = new Child();
c.method();
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20method()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log(%22test%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22result%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0A%09%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0Ac.method()%3B)

You can run the transpiled code in your browser's console

Comment: Yes, this code works. And this awesome, I love TypeScript and ES6 for that I do not have to write in the old (constructor/prototype) :)

But specifically in this single-site I need old method.

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to answer your question but what about: 1) https://medium.com/@PitaJ/javascript-inheritance-patterns-179d8f6c143c#.dt8ke7eb0 using a *JavaScript inheritance pattern* or 2) just copying output of TypeScript transpilation?

Comment: No :) I can implements inheritance. I need explain result to TypeScript.